# Spring Framework Open Redirect Vulnerability on Nifi 1.19.1

Tags: apache-nifi

The current installation of Nifi 1.19.1 is scanned for the Spring Framework Open Redirect vulnerability. Can I directly upgrade to apache nifi1.25.0? Or is there any other solution? Currently, considering that the code supports Java 8, upgrading to apache1.* and apache nifi2 seems to be a version of spring Framework that is still a risky version. Upgrading to nifi2 requires upgrading Java.

Comment: you can upgrade. focus on components described here if you are using them https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Migration+Guidance#MigrationGuidance-Migratingto1.24.0
IMHO you can ignore this vulnerability  because normally nifi UI is not exposed to end users.